# Layout content container doesn't grow with its content

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a web app layout, that consists of navigation bar, side navigation and page content. Unfortunately with current setup, page content container it doesn't grow with content. https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-allen-9ycgq4

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", height: "3.25rem" }}>
        Global navigation
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          padding: "1rem",
          gap: "1rem",
          height: "calc(100vh - 3.25rem)",
          width: "100%",
          maxWidth: "1600px",
          overflow: "auto",
          boxSizing: "border-box"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            width: "15rem",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            position: "sticky",
            top: "0",
          }}
        >
          Side navigation
        </div>
        <div style={{ flexGrow: "1" }}>
          <div style={{ height: "150%", backgroundColor: "green" }}>
            Main content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Is there a way to make this component with flex-grow: 1 have full height of it's children, not only screen size?

The reason I'm asking is because when i have this height of `150%`, when i scroll down, padding of `1rem` is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT EDIT: Ok, now I finally got what u needed [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-swirles-y2qlpd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: It looks like, your example doesn't really match my case. Could you try implementing that on my code?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understood your needs correctly. If you want to achieve a scroll behaviour only on the page content I provided you a new sandbox.

Comment: I updated the sandbox, try it and let me know :)

Comment: The behavior is almost correct. Problem is that i cant have scroll on main content only (design requirements). Scroll should be placed on container that wraps both navigation and content. If you see my sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-allen-9ycgq4) you will notice that when you scroll down, main content doesn't have padding bottom. What i need is exact same behavior as i have, but main content to have padding bottom.

Comment: I think I finally got what you were trying to say. See the updated sandbox and let me know

Comment: Well you are close one again. But what you did was using "px" to set the height. Do you know a way to make main content have a full height without setting height in "px"? To be of the same height as navigation, and always have this padding on bottom, even if bigger.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).